# how to programatically fetch xpaths of all elements on a web page from any browser

Tags: java, javascript, xpath, ui-automation, domxpath

I am newbie to Web UI automation and as part of it, we require to fetch and store the Xpaths of all the elements such as labels, buttons, hyperlinks, textboxes, checkboxes, radiobuttons, images etc into a file. Also the UI scripts are executed in different browsers like IE, FireFox and Chrome.

Could someone help me with an advice or suggestion, of how to fetch Xpaths of all the elements easily in a quick time.

Answer (score 0):

1. create a Java program to connect to URL, in user agent of y ,pour code, set the user agent of the browser you want to simulate.
2. use a HTML Dom parser, like jtidy or any other to parse the input stream into a HTML Dom
3. now you can find all different elements which are present on the page
4. then your xpaths will be //elementname

Comment: Hi Abhinav, Thanks for your reply. Could you elaborate it a little more please. I am totally new, so if any there is sample code then that would be very helpful